# How to make this subgroup Table

Tags: r, datatable, cox-regression, tbl

How to make this type of table in R ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's kind of a big question and you really should give us some sample data and code so we can see where you're starting from. But I think with `ggplot2` you could use `geom_point` to plot the circle, `geom_hline` to plot the confidence interval line, and `facet_wrap` to split into US and European samples.

Comment: Agree with @C.Murtaugh - I would consider using `geom_segment` to plot the confidence interval line rather than `geom_hline`. Even better, check out `geom_pointrange` which is made for visualizing error. Check out this book: https://ggplot2-book.org/statistical-summaries.html

Comment: Good call on both `geom_segment` and `geom_pointrange`, the latter of which I didn't even know about until now.